# Add a writing competition to our tag challenges?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

In the initial [tag challenge suggestion](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1925/33442) there was a comment suggestion we alternate between tag challenges and writing challenges. @Cyn has taken up the task and started creating our [weekly tag challenges](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1965/33442), participation so far is low but I think it's a good start.

I was thinking of ways to increase the participation in challenge and came back to the writing competition idea. [Liquid's answer](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1927/33442) said that the normal process for creating a new question is:

> -> write something -> a doubt comes up -> ask Writers SE.

Therefore if we are doing a writing challenge as well doubts will come up that are related to the tag of the week. So here is my suggestion.

#### Allow writing challenge entries as answers on the tag challenge question.

The writing challenge should in some way incorporate the week's featured tags. They should probably be short as well <5000 words should keep it below the answer character limit if we wanted the whole text within the answer.

As a community we can use votes to choose a winner for the week. We could either have a writing winner and an asking winner or come up with a scoring system that combined the two.

How do people feel about adding a writing challenge to the question tag challenge?

---

Possibly it would be good to announce next weeks tags ahead of time so that people have time to write entries and think of questions. But that would be a trial and error process.

Comment: While there are pros and cons to a community that allows sharing of our written work, getting critiques (judgment is a critique) has been declared 100% off topic.  As tempting as it is, it would forever change the character of this place.

Comment: @Cyn That's fair enough. I'm not 100% committed to the idea myself. It was mentioned in comment a few places and thought it should get an actual meta-post. It would be good if we could increase tag of the week participation.

Answer (score 1):

Who would assess them? It's another layer of work.

Also, I feel like the SE network incentivizes us to have more questions (both daily and per tag), but excess answers are unnecessary.  So while "forcing" a question is a good thing, "forcing" an answer, when there are already a few good ones, is pointless.

Comment: "As a community we can use votes to choose a winner for the week", this isn't about forcing answers to question. This is about encourage people to write. The entries would be here on meta not on the main site.